# unable to update excel sheet data into sql server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, web-applications, excel-2007

We have an asp.net application supported by sql server 2008 R2.
There is an option to update or insert entries in the database from an excel sheet. After selecting the file for upload, when i click on update button, the page gets refreshed and nothing else happens. The database wont get updated. 
I tried debugging the code and to my surprise, it worked fine! Tried many times and the same thing happens. Won't update from the application but updates when debugged! I know posting the code will help people understand the problme better bu am not allowed to post any code as per the policy of my organization. My apologies.
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  I think in code u mentioned the Sheet name wrong so that it can't be inserted.
>
> may this code helps u..
> ```

```
string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = excelConnectionString;
                string qry = "write query here "' from [Sheet1$]";
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(qry, connection);
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=A115-PC;Initial Catalog=ErpDB;User ID=sa;Password=XYZ@123";
            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
            SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
            bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "MTPractiBilling"; // table name
            bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);

            DataSet dsClient = new DataSet();
            dsClient = ccSql.pBindDataSet("Select Path,FileSize,DocumentName from MTPractiBilling where UploadName='" + uploadnm + "'");
            if (dsClient.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= dsClient.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    clpath = dsClient.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();

                    FSize = dsClient.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    DocNm = dsClient.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                    string s = clpath;
                    string[] words = s.Split('\\');
                    clpath = words[4];
                    scpath = words[4];
                    clpath = ccSql.pReturnSingleValue “ personal query'");
                    scpath = ccSql.pReturnSingleValue("personal query' "");
                    int cnt = ccSql.pReturnIntegerValue("personal query'"'");
                    //int match = ccSql.pReturnInteger("personal query'");
                    if (cnt <= 0)
                    {
                        ccSql.pExecuteQuery("personal query''");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ccSql.pExecuteQuery("personal query''");
                        Label1.Text = DocNm.ToString() + "-" + FSize.ToString() + " Already Billed or Process..";
                        return;
                    }
                }
```